# Is there a way to have a generic XmlAdapter for custom types in CXF?

Tags: java, cxf

I am using custom types for my CXF service and all of they can be serialized into JSON using Jackson. CXF provides the [XmlAdapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html) for converting between XML and the custom datatypes. The issue I'm having is that the XmlAdapter can take only one BoundType in the generic, so I'm finding myself writing one adapter for each data type which seems wasteful.

Basically I have:

```
public class JsonAdapter<T> extends XmlAdapter<String, T> {
    private final Class<T> type;
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public JsonAdapter(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
        this.objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }

    @Override
    public T unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return objectMapper.readValue(v, type);
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(T v) throws Exception {
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(v);
    }
}
```

And then for each type I have to write another adapter:

```
class MyTypeAdapter extends MyTypeAdapter<Client> {
    public MyTypeAdapter() {
        super(MyTypeAdapter.class);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this with only one adapter?

Comment: Your `MyTypeAdapter` does not seem right. The constructor is named `ClientAdapter`. Maybe you need to double-check your code in the question.

Comment: I renamed types to make it more generic. That doesn't really affect the content of the question. Thanks for pointing out the typo.